# docker entrypoint sh file restarting

Tags: php, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am testing docker with my php project. Everything is ok in testing but if I add **ENTRYPOINT**, docker is restarting.

Here is my docker compose file

```
version: "3.7"
services:

#Laravel App
  app:
    build:
      args:
        user: maruan
        uid: 1000
      context: ./docker/7.4
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
   #  command: sh -c "start-container.sh"
    image: laravel-app
    restart: unless-stopped
    working_dir: /var/www/
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www
    networks:
      - app-network
    
 #Nginx Service
  nginx:
    image: nginx:alpine
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - 8000:80
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www
      - ./docker/7.4/nginx/conf.d:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
    networks:
      - app-network
  #Mysl Service
  db:
    image: mysql:8
    restart: unless-stopped
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: ${DB_DATABASE}
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${DB_PASSWORD}
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: ${DB_PASSWORD}
      MYSQL_USER: ${DB_USERNAME}
    networks:
      - app-network
      
networks:
  app-network:
    driver: bridge
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM php:7.4-fpm

# Arguments defined in docker-compose.yml
ARG user
ARG uid

WORKDIR /var/www

ENV TZ=UTC
RUN ln -snf /usr/share/zoneinfo/$TZ /etc/localtime && echo $TZ > /etc/timezone

# Install system dependencies
RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends build-essential mariadb-client libfreetype6-dev libjpeg-dev libpng-dev libwebp-dev zlib1g-dev libzip-dev gcc g++ make vim unzip git jpegoptim optipng pngquant gifsicle locales libonig-dev \
    && docker-php-ext-configure gd  \
    && docker-php-ext-install gd \
    && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends libgmp-dev \
    && docker-php-ext-install gmp \
    && docker-php-ext-install mysqli pdo_mysql zip \
    && docker-php-ext-enable opcache \
    && apt-get autoclean -y \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* \
    && rm -rf /tmp/pear/


COPY . /var/www

# Get latest Composer
COPY --from=composer:latest /usr/bin/composer /usr/bin/composer


# Create system user to run Composer and Artisan Commands
RUN useradd -G www-data,root -u $uid -d /home/$user $user
RUN mkdir -p /home/$user/.composer && \
    chown -R $user:$user /home/$user

COPY start-container.sh /usr/local/bin/start-container.sh
RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/start-container.sh


ENTRYPOINT ["start-container.sh"]
```

start-container.sh file

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

set -e

cd /var/www  
php artisan optimize
php artisan view:cache
#composer install && composer dump-autoload

exec "$@"
```

I also print log for that docker image.

```
Configuration cached successfully!
Route cache cleared!
Routes cached successfully!
Files cached successfully!
Compiled views cleared!
Blade templates cached successfully!
```

I think my error is **docker container is restarting after running start-container.sh file**. When I google, some people use **PHP artisan** script with ENTRYPOINT sh file.

What should I do not to restart again and again with ENTRYPOINT sh file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your entrypoint script ends with the line `exec "$@"`.  This runs the image's `CMD`, and is generally a best practice.  However, your image doesn't have a `CMD`, so that command just expands to a bare `exec`, which causes the main container process to exit.

An image built `FROM php:fpm` often won't have a `CMD` line since the base image's [Dockerfile](https://github.com/docker-library/php/blob/a1fd650238cd68fbf3e1998f4ce4ea4ad5324dac/8.0/buster/fpm/Dockerfile) specifies `CMD ["php-fpm"]`; it is enough to `COPY` your application code into a derived image, and the base image's `CMD` knows how to run it.  However, setting `ENTRYPOINT` in a derived image resets the `CMD` from the base image (see the note in the [Dockerfile documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#understand-how-cmd-and-entrypoint-interact) discussing `CMD` and `ENTRYPOINT` together).  This means you need to repeat the base image's `CMD`:

```sh
ENTRYPOINT ["start-container.sh"]
CMD ["php-fpm"] # duplicated from base image, because you reset ENTRYPOINT
```

Comment: You beat me to it

Comment: Oh ! You saved me. Thanks for your explanation